# Set useState and pass state somewhere, then return state to initial

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have useState episodesUrl which takes object when clicked. I need to reset to inital value, it returns always true after clicked, and the logic below didn't work. I can't find approach to solve this. How to set to initial state after the logic executed?

```
src={
      episodesUrl[0].episodeUrl != undefined
      ? episodesUrl[0].episodeUrl
      : episode[0].episodeUrl != undefined
      ? episode[episode.length - 1].episodeUrl
      : stSeason[stSeason.length - 1].episodeUrl
                    }
```

Comment: Please, rephrase your question and show more code of your component.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to set the state to its initial value. What you can do is run all your logic that you need, then at the end of the function you can manually reset it to the initial state. Or you can have a different function that is called whenever you need to reset it.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
...
const functionClick = () => {
    // Whatever logic you need here
    setState(newState);
    // Whatever logic you need here
    setState(initialState);
}
```